# C# using OpenXml.Spreadsheet to populate a DataGrid

Tags: c#, datatable, openxml

I'd like to populate a DataTable with values from a speadsheet using the OpenXml.Spreadsheet reference. Unfortunately, my method isn't working very well. I'm getting an object refernce not set to an instance of an object error. Can you advise on the best course of action? Looks like myCollection.Add(text) seems to be breaking it.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;


public DataTable ReadXls(string filePath)
    {       
        // create a new datatable

        DataTable xlsData = new DataTable();
        DataTable xlsDataOut = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
            {
                // invoke spreadsheet stuff

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

                // determine number of rows/columns to create DataTable

                foreach (Column col in sheetData.Elements<Column>())
                {
                    DataColumn serialno = new DataColumn();
                    serialno.AllowDBNull = true;
                    xlsData.Columns.Add(serialno);
                }

                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    DataRow dtRow = xlsData.NewRow();
                    xlsData.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                }

                // column and row count for dataset
                int colcount = xlsData.Columns.Count;
                int rowcount = xlsData.Rows.Count;

                // invoke individual cell 

                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();
                    DataRow dr = xlsDataOut.NewRow();

                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        string text = c.CellValue.Text;
                        myCollection.Add(text);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < colcount; i++)
                    {
                        dr[i] = myCollection[i];
                    }

                    xlsDataOut.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error creating DataTable from xls file" + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return xlsDataOut;
    }
```

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" easy enough, but on which line?

Comment: I doubt `sheetData.Elements<Column>()` is returning anything. Is it? Last time I tried, I had to iterate over cells to determine column count.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and this works. Special thanks to it_Saige from Experts Exchange.

```
public void btnOpenExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Upload data from .xls file
        try
        {
            // Pulls up file reader

            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "xlsx|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    lblFileName.Text = ofd.FileName;

                    // use selected file name to populate Spreadsheet Viewer
                    var myData = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ofd.FileName, false).GetDataTableFromSpreadSheet();
                    dataGridView.DataSource = myData;

                }
            }             
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

static class Extensions
{
    // this extension is for populating the GridView with values from a spreadsheet. 
    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromSpreadSheet(this SpreadsheetDocument document, int columns = -1, bool excludeHeader = true)
    {
        var results = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            var sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            var id = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            var part = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(id);
            var sheet = part.Worksheet;
            var data = sheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var rows = data.Descendants<Row>();
            if (rows.Count() != 0)
            {
                var colCount = rows.First().Cast<Cell>().Count();
                if (columns > colCount || columns <= 0)
                    columns = colCount;

                foreach (var cell in rows.First().Cast<Cell>().Take(columns))
                    results.Columns.Add(cell.GetValue(document));

                foreach (var row in rows.Skip(Convert.ToInt32(excludeHeader)))
                    results.Rows.Add((from cell in row.Cast<Cell>().Take(columns) select cell.GetValue(document)).ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            results = new DataTable();
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static string GetValue(this Cell cell, SpreadsheetDocument document)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (cell != null && cell.ChildElements.Count != 0)
            {
                var part = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
                if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                    result = part.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)].InnerText;
                else
                    result = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = string.Empty;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```